# Removing Scroll Bar on Joomla 3 SqueezBox

Tags: javascript, css, joomla

I am using Joomla 3 and Splashr to create a modal popup that displays content using an iframe.  The module uses the SqueezeBox.Open method to spawn the modal on page load.

**The problem** is that the iframe has a scroll bar on the right side.

**What I have tried to remove it:**

**CSS:**

```
sbox-content iframe { 
    overflow:hidden !important;
}
```

**JS Modification:**

```
SqueezeBox.open('./pop-up', {
    "handler":"iframe",
    "style"  : {
        "overflow":"hidden"
    },
    "size"   : {
        "x":"600",
        "y":"600"
    }
});

SqueezeBox.open('./pop-up', {
    "handler":"iframe",
    "options": {
        "scrolling":"no"
    },
    "size"   : {
        "x":"600",
        "y":"600"
    }
});
```

Usually I would just add `scrolling="no"` to the iframe HTML, but that HTML code is generated by the javascript.

Is there a way to insert the `scrolling="no"` in to the iframe via the `SqueezeBox.open()` JS OR is there some other method I can use to remove the scroll bar?